# Android,GoogleAnalytics - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I'm using GoogleAnalyticsServicesAndroid_3.0, And Have a min sdk of Android API  9.

I keep seeing the following error in my bug report system :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileOutput(ContextImpl.java:431)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:158)
at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.ClientIdDefaultProvider.storeClientId(ClientIdDefaultProvider.java:102)
at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.ClientIdDefaultProvider.generateClientId(ClientIdDefaultProvider.java:123)
at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.ClientIdDefaultProvider.initializeClientId(ClientIdDefaultProvider.java:179)
at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.ClientIdDefaultProvider$1.run(ClientIdDefaultProvider.java:134)
```

I haven't been able to find a solution for this, Any help is appreciated

This seems to only happen in 2.3.  OS versions
Thanks,
Shimi

Comment: You may wish to include some code. Here's the documentation for NullPointerExceptions, which is worth a read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

Comment: What should i add ? at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileOutput(ContextImpl.java:431)

Comment: I got the same issue on 2.3.3. my client device gives this error report via Google Crashes and ANR report

Comment: same issue happened to me. But it happened for the first time, from millions of sessions only once. So not sure how it relates to your case.